# Spring-Aspects / Should ConfigurableDeserializationSupport have public access instead of package access?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-aspects

I am running into issues with Intellij (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-316370) and other code like the type-pollution-agent about an invalid super class for classes using @Configurable that are also Serializable.

For example, you get an error like "Cannot access 'org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AbstractInterfaceDrivenDependencyInjectionAspect$ConfigurableDeserializationSupport' which is a supertype of XYZ class".

I am not an expert on spring-aspects or aspectj. Hence, this question to ascertain if this should be a ticket in spring-aspects since the github repo doesn't take questions. It states questions should be submitted here.

I'm curious if anyone knows if ConfigurableDeserializationSupport is intentionally set to package access. I am trying to determine if this should be a spring-aspects ticket or something else.